# how to swipe text in same cell or rearange in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet and i want to change position of text in cell for ex:

```
cell A                 | Cell B
----------------------------------------------
hd photo this is my    | this is my hd photo
-----------------------------------------------
pen this is my         | this is my pen         
------------------------------------------------
your name what is      | what is your name
```

I have cell A values and want to value like Cell B . hope you understand my question. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to move the **first two** words to the end or only the **first word** to the end ???

Comment: @Gary'sStudent hi , its different values in every row .. not same so in some need 2 first words in some 3 words in some 1 or may be in some even 4  hope you understand . thanks

Comment: How is the formula to know how many words to move ??

Comment: 3 words are mostly in my sheet , so 3 word looks done lot of my work .

Comment: @Gary'sStudent sorry for  i dont understand it first reading . yes you are right formula need to put value how many words to change . so i will put it according to  my sheet requirement . if one sheet need first 2 words be change i will put 2 in formula if i got . i try in google but not get anything or any help regrading   this . thanks for your time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function rotate(s As String, Kount As Long) As String
    ary = Split(s, " ")
    ReDim bry(0 To UBound(ary))
    j = 0

    For i = Kount To UBound(ary)
        bry(j) = ary(i)
        j = j + 1
    Next i

    For i = 0 To Kount - 1
        bry(j) = ary(i)
        j = j + 1
    Next i

    rotate = Join(bry, " ")
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

The first argument is the cell containing the original text and the second argument is the number of words to be shifted to the end of the phrase.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as `.xlsm` rather than `.xlsx`

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=rotate(A1,3)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: thanks dear this is working .. this is what  i need . thanks for your help . im not able to vote your answer .. but when ever my rank is able to vote to answer i will vote this answer .. thanks dear again ..